# Water vapor using Landsat-8

Tags: landsat-8, land-surface-temperature

I want to compute Land Surface Temperature using Landsat-8 images, and to do so I have to calculate the water vapor first, I found out that a lot of people use the MSWCVR method which I don't quite understand, I'm wondering if someone can explain it to me in a simple way, or suggest another effective method?